# How to generate a unique random number when insert in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, random

I have a database for articles and may want to generate a unique random integer for each articles so that they can be visited through URL like https://blablabla.com/articles/8373734 etc.

I could achieve that in python backend, but how do we achieve this in MySQL sentences?

For example, a new article was done, and inserted into database:

```
INSERT into article_table (title, date, url_id) VALUES ('asdf', '11/11/1111', 8373734)
```

the url_id here is the unique random integer (1000~10000000) that automatically generated.

I believe The primary key ID and auto-increasment are good way to solve this. But my question is:

1. In practical scenario, do they (companies) literally use primary ID or auto-increasment? This may expose how piece of data you (ever) have in database. Take this https://www.zhihu.com/question/41490222 for example, I tried hundreds of number around 41490222, all returns 404 not found. it seems that the number are recorded very sparsely, not very possible achieved by auto-increasement.
2. Are there any efficient way to generate such random number without checking duplication for every loop?

Comment: Just use an auto-incremented id.

Comment: Why does it have to be random? An auto-increment integer column guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: May be UUID_SHORT() can be used

Comment: because I don't want the integer to be consecutive

Comment: Do you _really_ need your IDs to be numeric? Can they be strings?

Comment: string would be okay, I just found pure number in url address would be well-looked.

Comment: Isn't there a chance (however slim) that it could return a random number that matches an already existing number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

albeit my sql skills are a bit rusty, I think you might want to create a function using the RAND function.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRandomValue()
BEGIN

  DECLARE newUrlId INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE (
    newUrlId = 0 
    OR IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE url_id = newUrlId)
  )
  DO
    SET newUrlId = SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 999999)
  END WHILE

  RETURN newUrlId
END
```

Then again, why creating such a fuss while you could use other ways to create "bigger random numbers"

for example:

```
function createBiggerNumber(id) {
  return (id * constants.MySecretMultiplyValue) + constants.MySecretAddedValue;
}

function extractIdFromBiggerNumber(number) {
  return (number - constants.MySecretAddedValue) / constants.MySecretMultiplyValue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), or if it has to be numeric [`UUID_SHORT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) for that.

Comment: Yes, this seems good, but would it really be unique? The database is frequently switched to different servers for backup and data acquiring.

Comment: If you use `UUID()`, you'll get a 128-bit value, which is practically unique. The chances of a collision are negligibly low. The constraints of `UUID_SHORT()` are described in the linked documentation.

Comment: is uuid_short is auto-increased? I found they increase in step on my server from 25265837279543337

Comment: I am wondering, would ENCRYPT() function in mysql would be unique? For example, ENCRYPT(NOW())

Answer (score 0):

```
Use mysql function RAND()
-------------------------

select FLOOR(RAND() * 999999)
```

Comment: I am wondering, would ENCRYPT() function in mysql would be unique? For example, ENCRYPT(NOW())

Comment: After 100 000 rows you will have doubles, not really unique. If you want to match posted requirements of uniques you will have to up the number to 9 999 999. The other thing is you get doubles before you even reach that number, so not really a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

the logic is combine with their primary key | id , so we dont need re check if the data is exist or not.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `auto_number`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `auto_number` BEFORE INSERT on users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET new.auto_number = CONCAT(new.id, LEFT(UUID(), 8));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

https://gist.github.com/yogithesymbian/698b27138a5ba89d2a32e3fc7ddd3cfb